# Issue-Integrate Authorized.Net payment gateway in Android

Tags: android, authorize.net, authorize.net-cim

I am integrating [Authorized.Net Payment Gateway](https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/accept-sdk-android) in Android.

but in this above sdk,I am not passing amount of this Encrypted Trasaction.can anyone help me how to proceed simple payment transaction in Authorized.net android.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you create a transaction after receiving the payment nonce?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got solution of my question.
I am using above sdk

https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/accept-sdk-android

and I am passing credit card info to our server and then our server get all information from application and using webAPI call,Server send transaction information to authorised.net Server and get back to accessToken as a response.

Comment: you may direcly send transaction to authorised.net via android app  and also store/save credit card info to authorised.net or else your webserver.

Comment: Can't I make payment via my Android Device and Send the Transaction Id to the server. Rather than server making the payment with the details I have sent?

Answer (score 3):

Hello [this](https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sample-code-java/tree/master/src/main/java/net/authorize/sample/MobileInappTransactions) link may be helpful to you,try it and let me know if it work for you.

Comment: You link does not exist

Comment: maybe git remove that code let me check & update you